# Can I specify a verbose name in a manyToMany automatically generated model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have the following models:

```
class Doctor(models.Model):

    #some attributes...

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _(u'doctor')
        verbose_name_plural = _(u'doctors')


class Patient(models.Model):

    #some attributes...
    medical_consult = models.ManyToManyField(Doctor)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('patient')
        verbose_name_plural = _('patients')
```

Is there any way to set a `verbose_name` to the model `Patient_doctor` that is automatically created when I use the ManyToManyField?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
medical_consult = models.ManyToManyField(Doctor, through='PatientDoctor')

# ...

class PatientDoctor(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient)
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctor)
    # ...

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('patient_doctor')
        # ...
```